# Create a Date and Time in Java (not the .now)

Tags: java, date, time

I currently need to create my own dates (a user has to specify it), but it is not the current date.
I want in in the format specified in Joda Time. DateTime(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour, int secondOfMinute)

Although any alternative will help.
This is my code:

```java
DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(2020,10,9,12,30);
```

Comment: So what is wrong with that code? It does exactly what you say you want. What would you want differently?

Comment: You may look for date picker and time picker components for the user to specify date and time. Not sure there are any that are integrated with Joda-Time, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LocalDateTime` which is part of [the modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 10, 9, 12, 30);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-09T12:30
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

As suggested [here](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time), Joda-time is no longer in active development except to keep timezone data up to date. From Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

If you are doing it for your Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Lots of good suggestions.